# Multi-item clipboard in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, clipboard

Does VS2008 support a better clipboard with multiple items?

Answer (score 7):

The one feature I know that Visual Studio 2008 (Maybe 2005 but i can't remeber) has is the ability to cycle through the clipboard using Ctrl + Shift + V

There are however some limitations to this as it will only remeber items that have been "added" to the clipboard within Visual Studio.

I don't use the feature extensivly but it is useful.

Comment: Found this, it's kind of useful although a bit rough around the edges - I'd like to be able to keep the dialog open as a toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used one in vs2008 directly although you could write one in its own macro language I am sure. But you could use a windows general multi item clipboard like ClipX. http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/

There may be a better alternative to this on the market. This was just the results from a quick check about.

Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: How is it 2011 and we're still stuck with single-item clipboards as default on Windows & Mac? Word used to have a wonderful one (maybe it still does) but it would be so useful if it was part of the OS and used widely.

Answer (score 0):

[MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx) add-in offers [multiple private clipboards feature](http://www.mztools.com/v6/features.aspx#PrivateClipboards), amongst many others.